# help identify HotPoint oven model

Tags: oven

Please help identify the oven; it's pretty old, I guess middle 90s. I checked the model name/number placed on a tag inside the oven (as you open the door, it's in there), but I failed to find mode information on [www.hotpointservice.co.uk/manual/](http://www.hotpointservice.co.uk/manual/)

Perhaps someone could figure the model by picture?

[image]

**UPDATE**
And this is a metal tag at the bottom of the oven with information about the oven; I hope somebody could recognize it:

[image]

Comment: Turn off the breaker, move the oven out and see if there is a name plate on the back.

Comment: @WarLoki, no name plate was found at the back.

Answer (score 1):

I Googled [RCBS536](https://www.google.com/search?q=RCBS536) and found a number of references:

- A copy of the [manual](http://www.manualslib.com/products/Ge-Rcbs536-3483745.html)
- The unit on sale at [Best Buy Canada](http://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/product/hotpoint-hotpoint-30-5-cu-ft-easy-clean-coil-top-range-rcbs536dnww-white-rcbs536dnww/10327531.aspx)
- [Parts for sale](http://www.appliancepartspros.com/parts-for-ge-rcbs536wj1ww.html)